# Angular DataTable not showing data on page access but until i reload the page

Tags: jquery, angular, datatables, angular-datatables

I'm starting to learn Angular, I wanted to use Angular-DataTables to display my data (the backend part is working fine I'm calling a REST API and my Data is retrieved without any problem).

The problem is when I access my page containing the table it say No data available in table but when I click refresh my data appears I navigate to another page and go back to my page containing the table no data is showing until I refresh again.

Here's what I did:

app.module.ts

```
import { DataTablesModule } from 'angular-datatables';
.
.
.
.
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    DataTablesModule
  ],
```

purchases.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {PurchasesService} from './purchases-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-purchases',
  templateUrl: './purchases.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./purchases.component.scss']
})
export class PurchasesComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private purchaseService: PurchasesService) {
  }

  purchaseOrders;
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 5,
      processing: true,
      language: {
        'url': '../../assets/English.json'
      }
    };
    this.purchaseService.getOrders().subscribe((data) => {
      this.purchaseOrders = data;
    }, (err) => {
        console.log('-----> err', err);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

purchases.component.html

```
<table id="purchaseOrders" datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class=""> <!--row-border hover table table-striped -->
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th> Date </th>
              <th> Vendor </th>
              <th> Customer </th>
              <th> GrandTotal </th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let order of purchaseOrders">
              <td>{{order.date}}</td>
              <td>{{order.vendor}}</td>
              <td>{{order.receiver}}</td>
              <td>{{order.grandtotal}}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I would try is `cdr.detectChanges();` (that is, import chandeDetectorRef in your constructor via `private cdr: changeDetectorRef` and call the detectchanges method after you set `this.purchaseorders`

It could be the issue since a service is async, and the view renders before it's complete. This is usually handled automagically by angular on specific events (see https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html), one of which should be xhr requests.

If that doesn't work, I'd do experimenting with lifecycle hooks, best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't work i'll check with the link you provided

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property `dtTrigger` to manually trigger the rendering of the datatable after the data has been received.

purchases.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { PurchasesService } from './purchases-service.service';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-purchases',
  templateUrl: './purchases.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./purchases.component.scss']
})
export class PurchasesComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private purchaseService: PurchasesService) {
  }

  purchaseOrders;
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
  dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>(); //Ensuring the data is fetched first

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 5,
      processing: true,
      language: {
        'url': '../../assets/English.json'
      }
    };

    this.purchaseService.getOrders().subscribe((data) => {
      this.purchaseOrders = data;  //First, we receive the data

      this.dtTrigger.next(true);  //Then, we manually trigger the table to render
    }, (err) => {
      console.log('-----> err', err);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.dtTrigger.unsubscribe(); //Unsubscribe from an event we only need once
  }
}
```

purchases.component.html

```
<table id="purchaseOrders" datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger">
  <!-- Rest of HTML here -->
</table>
```

Also, I'd urge you not to forget to install all required libraries, after adding datatables with `ng add angular-datatables`.

```
npm install jquery --save
npm install datatables.net --save
npm install datatables.net-dt --save
npm install angular-datatables --save
npm install @types/jquery --save-dev
npm install @types/datatables.net --save-dev
```

Afterwards, you need to include the following within your `angular.json`.

```
...
"styles": [
  "node_modules/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css",
  ...
],
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
  "node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js",
  ...
],
...
```

The following link contains all the necessary information for you to make it work: [angular-datatables documentation](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started)